# MySQL 5.5 doesn't use index when using a CASE statement inside a WHERE clause

Tags: mysql

I have a table of vehicles with a VARCHAR(16) PRIMARY key on a field called "stockno". The table has over 9K records.  I am trying to to develop an api that returns a list of vehicles if a stockno arg is null otherwise it returns the specified stockno.  However when I run an EXPLAIN on the query below the index is not use.

```
SET @stockno = 'abc';
SELECT stockno FROM vehicles WHERE CASE WHEN @stockno IS NOT NULL THEN vehicles.stockno = @stockno ELSE 1 = 1 END
```

I have tried: `SELECT stockno FROM vehicles WHERE CASE WHEN @stockno IS NOT NULL THEN vehicles.stockno = CONVERT(@stockno USING latin1) ELSE 1 = 1 END`

Also when I run `SELECT stockno FROM vehicles WHERE stockno = 'abcdef'` the index is used.

**Edit**
This statement will eventually be used as a view.

Comment: Why don't you produce a different SQL statement depending on whether `@stockno` is null, with a `if else` statement?

Comment: @trincot this is where my head is at right now and that I should just create a dynamic sql statment through the API. I just wanted to understand why and to know if I wasn't missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reviewing the SQL I decided it was easiest to create a dynamic SQL string through the API.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the query to use UNION ALL

```
SET @stockno = 'abc';
SELECT stockno
FROM vehicles
WHERE @stockno IS NOT NULL
AND vehicles.stockno = @stockno
UNION ALL
SELECT stockno
FROM vehicles
WHERE @stockno IS NULL;
```

Comment: This works in isolation however I forgot to mention that this will eventually be transformed into a view and the query itself is a lot more complicated with other items in the WHERE clause. So I am not sure if UNION is a practical solution here.